# How to make gcc generate rotate instructions?

Tags: gcc, assembly, compilation, mips, compiler-optimization

I'm using the following C code:

```
  unsigned int d = 5;
  return (n >> d)|(n << (32 - d));
```

Here is the generated assembly using gcc 4.9.2 (`target=mips64-elf`, however I assume that the target you use in this case does not matter)

```
  sll $2,$4,27 
  sra $4,$4,5  

  or  $2,$2,$4 
  j $31
```

What should be the C construct to make gcc generate a rotate instruction?

Comment: It does matter what target you use, obviously. It also matters what cpu you specified, because not all mips have hardware rotate.

Comment: There might be a `__builtin_`-esque intrinsic provided by GCC

Comment: according to [See MIPS run](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=kk8G2gK4Tw8C&pg=PA217&lpg=PA217&dq=mips+rotate+instruction&source=bl&ots=c-0Sk6JyWw&sig=yScr_S6Aoa3yPY5Xvcylv_OFIrM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PmdcVPm4D4LiuQSt3IG4Aw&ved=0CEkQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=mips%20rotate%20instruction&f=false), rotate instructions are only available since MIPS32/64R2

Comment: [UTD's paper](https://www.utdallas.edu/~dodge/EE2310/lec14.pdf) said that "Note that in the MIPS computer, rol and ror are
pseudo instructions, which are actually performed
using both left and right shifts and an OR-ing of the
two resulting shifts" but without specific microarchitecture

Comment: I think UTD paper is out of date. MIPS64r2 does seem to have rotate opcodes http://scc.ustc.edu.cn/zlsc/lxwycj/200910/W020100308600769158777.pdf

Comment: So, have you used the `--march=mips64r2` option?

Comment: To separate "recognize the rotate pattern in C code" from "generate a rotate instruction", you could compile with `-fdump-tree-optimized` and look at the file it writes.

Comment: Yes I was compiling with -mips64r2. Here is what I see in dump file

;; Function rightRotate (rightRotate, funcdef_no=1, decl_uid=993, symbol_order=1)

rightRotate (int n)
{
  int _2;
  int _3;
  int _4;

  <bb 2>:
  # DEBUG d => 5
  _2 = n_1(D) >> 5;
  _3 = n_1(D) << 27;
  _4 = _3 | _2;
  return _4;

}
I think the issue is that the compiler hasnt been able to "recognise the rotate pattern"

Comment: I've just had a look at gcc's builtins and there's no rotate builtin both [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) and [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Target-Builtins.html#Target-Builtins). Did you try a higher optimization level?

Comment: Yes, I have tried O2, and O3. I am using the following flags to compile -mips64r2 -g -O3 -fno-delayed-branch

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/tree-ssa-forwprop.c?revision=217213&view=markup#l1758 gcc has code to recognize rotate, but it is still missing some https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62263.

Comment: Ah, your type needs to be unsigned, or the right shift won't do what you expect...

Comment: I think this should be closed, because you used `unsigned int` in the question but `int` in the source code. [GCC 4.1.2 recognizes the rotate even at `-O1`](https://godbolt.org/z/fiDvP7)

Answer (score 3):

From the dump you show in the comments, it appears that `n` is signed. This means that, if `n<0`, the right shift may not be the logical shift that you expect. To get a valid rotate pattern, you need to make `n` unsigned.